# Pass data between components in a new tab

Tags: javascript, angular, routes

I have an object in one component and I want to pass it to another component. The problem is that this other component will open in a new tab.

I tried to use the data service strategy, but when the tab opens, the data service object comes undefined.

I thought about using the querys params and passing in the url. But the object is very complex

My data service:

```
  @Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
  export class DataService {

   private anime: Anime;

   constructor() { }

   setAnime(anime: Anime) {
    this.anime = anime;
   }
   getAnime() {
    return this.anime;
   }
 }
```

Setting object in data service:

```
goToDetailsByService(anime: Anime) {
   this.dataService.setAnime(anime);
   //this.router.navigateByUrl('/details');
   window.open('/details');
}
```

Getting the anime object via service data:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  console.log(this.dataService.getAnime());
  this.anime = this.dataService.getAnime()

}
```

When accessing the details component via navigate router works

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think there are two ways to do it. The first one is **[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)** , the second one is **[PostMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage)**

### localStorage

we can use localstorage because storage can be read across windows, and there is a storage event fire when you write something to storage.

Here is the code example.

```
// parent window
localStorage.setItem("EVENT.PUB", JSON.stringify(anime));

// child widnow
window.addEventListener('storage', function(event) {
  console.log(event);
  const anime = JSON.parse(event.newValue);
}, false);
```

### postMessage

The `window.postMessage()` method safely enables communication between Window objects; e.g., between a page and a pop-up that it spawned, or between a page and an iframe embedded within it.

Here is the code example.

```
// parent window
const detailPage = window.open('/details');
detailPage.postMessage(anime, '*');
// important notice: anime should be object that can be serialize
// otherwise error will happen when execute this function.


// child window
window.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
  // get out the message
  console.log(event.data);
  // and you can even send message back to parent window too.
  event.source.postMessage('Got it!',  event.origin);
}, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, in a scenario where the object is relatively large, 10-15 MB, do you consider which strategy is better?

Comment: the size of the object is already exceed the maximum size of localstorage, so localstorage is no longer the option here. 

I am not sure about performance of postMessage when it handle large object. you can try it.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do it would be to use the browsers `localStorage` since that will keep the applicaton state between tabs. When you open a new tab the two web pages are seperate and the state doesn't carry over.

So using `localStorage` you can do..

**SET**

```
goToDetailsByService(anime: Anime) {
  localStorage.setItem('anime', JSON.stringify(anime));
  window.open('/details');
}
```

**GET**

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.anime = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('anime'));

  // here you can choose to keep it in the localStorage or remove it as shown below
  localStorage.removeItem('anime');
}
```

Comment: Thank you, a question, suppose my object is very large around 10-15 MB, is the local storage strategy still viable?

Comment: So LocalStorage can use up to 10mb of storage, what you could do is switch over to indexedDB which is another type of browser storage, that lets you store up to 50mb, another way to do it would to be set up firebase storage and create some api calls to get and set the anime object